# How to remove turn-style tub overflow cover?

Tags: plumbing, leak, drain

I've tried looking all over for a solution, but I've yet to find a solution that matches my situation.  The cover I have (I think) is supposed to turn so the hole is downwards so you can remove the screw to remove the cap.  However, this unit seems to be (somehow) installed upside-down.  The cap can rotate easily from the 12 o'clock to the 3 o'clock, but there's a rim inside that's mostly covering the screw inside.  I can also turn the cap (with some effort) from 12 o'clock to 10 o'clock but it sounds like something is cracking or grinding when I do.

I also tried removing the screw despite the metal rim inside, but it just loosened until it was pressing against that rim and wouldn't come out any more.

In case anyone is wondering, I'm trying to remove it because I think there's leaking happening behind there.

[image: turn-style overflow cover]

As requested, here's a closer picture of the hole in the cap.  I highlighted the screw head as it's hard to see.  You can see that the screw head in mostly covered by the stationary metal rim.

[image: screw inside overflow cap]

Comment: The overflow leads to the tub drain. You won't see much if you get the cap off, other than a passage leading to the drain.

Comment: I have leaking occurring and that overflow is the last place to look.  I'm hoping that after I get the cap off I can seal around it.

Comment: you may need to see it from the back side.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to start with the part that doesn't need cutting a hole in the wall. ;)

Comment: What does the plaque read?

Comment: "Jacuzzi whirlpool bath"  the plate on the wall is labelled "Stanadyne"

Comment: Does it only leak when water goes *through* the overflow? If not, I'd be shocked if you found anything even if you got it off - it can't leak anywhere there isn't water.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to find a reliable way to make the dripping sound I'm hearing in the wall, but I can't seem to find a way.  I poured water over every possible spot that could leak but the dripping sound wasn't consistent.  Regardless, it'd be nice to know how to take off that cap in case I ever need to do so...

Comment: Why don't you just pour some water in the overflow (plug the drain) to isolate it.

Comment: @DMoore That's what I did.  But while I did get some dripping sounds in the wall, it didn't happen every time.  I had even filled the tub up past the top of that cap.  (could hear the normal draining water sound)

Comment: Are you sure that your drain plug is working 100%?  You could have a slight problem with your drain seal (which is just some plumber's putty usually).

Comment: @DMoore - I'm pretty sure it's okay.  I had the tub filled for several hours with just a rubber stopper and didn't hear dripping.

Comment: @TimTisdall - If you take out rubber stopper and just close drain do you get the leak with water sitting in tub?

Comment: @DMoore - How would I close the drain without a stopper?  The turn-knob plug no longer works and the plug that was there is gone.  I use a rubber plug to stop the drain.

Comment: OK just checking, how about just pouring a few gallons of water slowly down the drain?

Comment: I'm not so sure that's even a drain or over flow in the photo. If that's a Jacuzzi that might be a water jet and the reason that it turns is to increase or decrease the water jet. Have you used the jets recently? And have you operated the jet nozzle?

Comment: @ojait - it's a drain.  The controls for the jets are on the sides of the tub.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you hear a grating sound and can only turn the over flow plate slightly is because it is attached to a bushing which is screwed into the over flow pipe. When you turn the cap it threads into the pipe. If you are concerned that water is leaking from the over flow drain pipe behind the tub there should be an access panel on the other side of the drain wall (usually). If there is no way to check the drain you may want to create an access so you can check. Other possible ways to check would be the floor under the tub (if there is space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is about how to remove the cover.  I'm pretty sure there's no leaking going on in there, but I'd still like to know how to remove the cap (or if it's even possible on this side).

Comment: Not a jet. got it. If you don't see any obvious fasteners, and turning left and right isn't loosening it... It must be pressure fitted. Possibly with spring clips. Have you tried prying it off with a putty knife? Is there a noticeable lip or edge that would indicate that it is a cover or cap?

Comment: @Tim Tisdall- What is that round shaped mark on the top of the cover? Could you post a close up of it?

Comment: ... added another photo.

Comment: @Tim Tisdall- Doesn't it look as if the inside view in the close up shows that the cap (outside piece) is connected from the inside piece (plug?). If so maybe spritz some liquid wrench into the opening, give it a couple of light strikes with a screwdriver inserted into the opening , and lent it simmer overnight. Then try unscrewing it (counter clockwise). ("I know ...I'm reaching for straws here ,but...)

Comment: sorry I just now noticed the description you included for the second photo..

Comment: @Tim- I contacted Jacuzzi and they needed the serial #. here's their email address: consumerassistance@jacuzzi.com, if you want to contact them yourself.

Comment: talk about above and beyond!!  :)  Unfortunately, I don't see anything on the tub with a serial number.  Also, I'm not even sure if the tub would have come with the overflow/stopper assembly or if that was added on separately.

Comment: From what I could extrapolate viewing Jacuzzi's more recent tub specs is that all of these tubs are supposed to have an access panel to allow for motor and pump work. It should be on the opposite side of any wall adjoin the tub. If not there might be an access panel that can be removed along the side. The pdf file showed it having catches on the panel that are held in by clips. The panel would be pried open to gain access.

Comment: Also, it appears that the tubs they produce now have the over flow drain included or installed off the assembly line, if that helps.

Comment: Lastly, as a desperate, final solution (and keep in mind the large selection at all hardware stores) drill the cover off. Or cut it with snips to have an unobstructed view of how it is secured to the tub.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how old or new this is. The last one I installed the metal cover snapped onto the part that is screwed on. May not have been aligned when it was snapped on. Try "gently" to pry the cover off. Yours may be one piece but seeing how the screw is misaligned I'm thinking it's two pieces. They make the cover snap on so same base can be used with different finishes. Is there a brand?

Comment: It's a Jacuzzi.