# Can't remove twist-style / turn-style / knob cap on overflow drain in tub

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, overflow

I have an American Standard brand tub with jets. Its drain has a pop-up stopper, and the stopper is controlled not by a lever, but by one of these twist-style knobs, placed over the overflow drain. I removed the screw holding the cap in place (see the right-hand picture), but no matter what I do, I can't pull the cap off:

[image]

I've looked around inside as best I could to see if there's some other mechanism holding it in place, but I don't see anything. I don't think this thing has been removed in 15 years. I've tried turning it this way and that, pushing it in and out in case there's some kind of special release. I've tried knocking it with a hammer to loosen things up or try to break up deposits. I've tried vinegar, and then WD-40. I've tried using big screwdrivers as levers between the cap and the plate behind it. Nothing, refuses to come off.

There's another question here from someone with a similar problem, but in their case, they couldn't get the screw out, and the problem wasn't answered anyway:
[How to remove turn-style tub overflow cover?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40509/how-to-remove-turn-style-tub-overflow-cover)

Anyone have any ideas? Or does this need to be sawed off? Can a plumber handle this?

EDIT #1: here's a closer look at the area where the cap meets the stem--nice and gross:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Well done on your first post - you'd be amazed to see how many people don't include pictures. You _could_ saw it off, but that guarantees you'd have to replace it, but hang out - someone will most likely have a better answer for you.

Comment: have you tried spinning the cap?

Comment: @jsotola yup, the cap spins fine. But that's about all it does.

Comment: you may have to clamp the stem with needlenose pliers

Comment: @jsotola The cap seems fused to the stem. They spin 1 to 1. And I can't fit my needle-nose pliers into the gap between the cap and plate anyway, just tried it. I also tried just now to use a flathead screwdriver to chip at the meeting place between the cap and stem, just in case I could clear some deposit or loosen it etc, but nothin doin.

Comment: check the American Standard website for parts catalog ... there may be a drawing available which you could study ... you could also make a tool to clamp the stem  ... two parallel flat metal bars that would fit behind the knob, hinged together at one end ... the other end could be squeezed together with pliers or a bolt and nut

Comment: @jsotola you're suggesting I try to keep the stem from rotating (keep it still), while rotating the cap, to break the bond that way? The stem is round, and it's obscured by some other stuff, so I don't know if that's possible. I attached another pic to the original post to give you an idea. I'd also looked up parts info on American Standard's website, but can't find anything relevant. This thing is at least 15 years old, and I can't find the model number or any other info, unfortunately.

Comment: From your new pic, I would _guess_ that this is supposed to pry off, but that 15+ years of gunk have built up to "weld" it in place. Try pouring something like [CLR™](https://clrbrands.com/Products/CLR-Household/CLR-Calcium-Lime-Rust-Remover) (_no particular endorsement, just a brand I'm aware of_) on it to see if that will help. You may have to get creative with a baggie full of it, placed over the knob and tied up to allow it to soak. Maybe a balloon would work (don't know, never tried, it may get dissolved by the chemicals) to hold the decalcifier in place.

Comment: @FreeMan good call. I tried a few things, but no go. I ended up taking my anger out on the knob (see my own answer to post below). Then I tried soaking the thing in CLR, and even then it refused to come un-fused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answering my own question.) After trying a million things, I went with the destructive option. I used a metal file to shave a hole into the knob so I could access the screws on the plate behind it. I unscrewed the screws, turning the knob to be able to access each screw, and then took the whole assembly out. Afterwards, I soaked the still-fused-together knob and plate in CLR for 10 hours, and by the end, it still didn't come apart. After looking closer, it *might* be the case that the knob was held in place by a screw on the opposite side of the plate, which, when mounted to the tub, is completely inaccessible unless you open up the wall behind the tub and cut into the overflow waste pipe. What genius designed this?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. Be sure to give yourself a check mark, too!